# How to improve the performance of stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have 2 questions about improving the performance of stored procedure:

1) In SELECT clause:

```
,CASE WHEN vatcs.CashDeskId IN (1293,1296,1295) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END    --Кассы-метро
,CASE WHEN vatcs.CashDeskId IN (21,994,1137,1150,1162,1163,1282,1314,1327,1328) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END    --Кассы-остальные
,CASE WHEN vatcs.CashDeskId IN (988) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END    --Портал 2.0
,CASE WHEN vatcs.CashDeskId IN (1089,1088,122,1085,1087,1084,1086,270) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END --Евросеть
,CASE WHEN ISNULL(vatcs.CashdeskID, 0) NOT IN (1293,1296,1295,21,994,1137,1150,1162,1163,1282,1314,1327,1328,988,1089,1088,122,1085,1087,1084,1086,270)
```

Is it possible to speed it up?

2) In WHERE clause:

```
WHERE vatcs.SoldDate >= @beginDate
      AND vatcs.SoldDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @endDate)
```

I'm not sure if it's sargable and if not how can I make it to be sargable?

Comment: `Or` clause is faster than `in`, at some places you can use `or` clasuse where values to compare with is not too much.

Comment: Yes. I've thought the same. Does it mean I shouldn't use OR in case I have too much values in IN(...)?

Comment: Don't do that, IN is a actually like a shorthand for OR.

Comment: Did you specify indexes on CashDeskId and SoldDate?

Comment: I forgot to write that data comes from view that doesn't have indexes because there are outer joins in it.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing you can do about the CASE.

As for the WHERE clause, it should use INDEX on SoldDate if such one exist (yes your WHERE clause is Sargable).

But in case, the first time (in a long time) you run the query, the date range is so wide, sql server makes a full scan, you could have a parameter sniffing problem.

So, it might be good to use a query hint in order to force the index usage (you wouldn't lose much performance where full scan would have been more efficient anyway).

```
FROM dbo.vatcs WITH (INDEX(IDX_vatcsInnerTable_SoldDate)
```

Comment: I forgot to write that data comes from view that doesn't have indexes because there are outer joins in it.

Comment: Is SoldDate a computed value? If not, does it exists an index on it? Because you should be able to use the view's "child" table's index.

Comment: The SoldDate is not computed value. It comes from a table that is in selected columns in that view. I'm not sure what you mean on "you should be able to use the view's "child" table's index". How can I do that?

Comment: You should be able to refer to the index outside the view.